# Change class depending on current URL (Condition)

Tags: url, conditional-statements, tumblr

is it possible to change class attributes depending on current URL of post natively with tumblr conditions?

I want to change the highlight in the navigation depending on what page I am currently on and therefor I want to set or remove the class *active*:

```
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Kategorien</a>
```

Thanks for any advice!
rainer

Comment: Please specify which parts of the URL are necessary for you (if its a post-id, whatever).